# Default Color for UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, popup, uialertview, look-and-feel

I created a custom popup using UIView that behaves like UIAlertView. Currently, its backgroudColor is LightGray. But I want to give it exactly same look as the standard UIAlertView. Please suggest how can I acheive this functionality? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

give your view's background color #DCDCDC and opacity 20%.

Comment: but it does not glow like in-built UIAlertView.